# GIT LFS (Only application/vnd.git-lfs and application/vnd.git-lfs+json are supported)

Tags: git, git-lfs

LFS support has been working for a long time with our Azure GIT repo but suddenly it fails when pushing commits with large files. It start to upload. It looks like it starts over several times and then it fails.

```
C:\Git\...>git push
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://...@dev.azure.com/.../.../_git/....git/info/lfs.locksverify true
LFS: Client error: https://...@dev.azure.com/.../.../_git/.../info/lfs/objects/... from HTTP 413
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 18 MB/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/.../.../_git/...'
```

The Client error is: Only application/vnd.git-lfs and application/vnd.git-lfs+json are supported

Using:

- git version 2.33.1.windows.1
- git-lfs/3.0.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.1)

**Update**
The problem is consistent. Adding a new file produces the same error. I have reinstalled GIT/GIT-LFS, and cleaned the GIT repo folder. No change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-lfs%5D+HTTP+413

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled upon this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-lfs-push-got-413-error/867488 while investigating. Invoking the command below solves my issue.

```
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
```